# Analysing a Digital/Analog signal via Microphone

Tags: audio, analysis

I just need to be pointed in the right direction as I may be in over my head here.

If I wanted to write a program to analyze a sound wave how would I go about this?

I have an idea that it will involve a mixture of a maths package (like mathematica or matlab) and C or C++ but not sure where to start.

I'm only wondering at the moment but any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I'm new but not inept and a good challenge is always the best way to learn.

Comment: What kind of analysis? Speech-recognition, spectral,...?

Comment: I want to analyse the sound waveform and match it against a database.

Comment: What kind of waveform?  What kind of database?  What properties do you want to match?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica and Matlab can both take .wav files as inputs.